# Extend "name" for custom record type

Tags: clojure

I have a record that includes a `:name`. Is there any way to tell `clojure.core/name` how to extract the `:name` out of my record?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're able to change the `defrecord` declaration, simply implement the `clojure.lang.Named` interface there.

```
(defrecord MyRecord [name]
  clojure.lang.Named
  (getName [this]
    (:name this)))

(name (MyRecord. "Dan"))
;;=> "Dan""
```

Comment: Agree with the approach, I would add just one thing: the assumption that the record declaration is owned must be a necessary *precondition* for implementing the interface that is *not* owned. At the very least, if neither a type/record and an interface/protocol are owned such implementation needs to be very carefully considered. [Clojure library coding standards](http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Library+Coding+Standards) include this rule for protocols, but it obviously applies to interfaces as well. (I don't think that OP has this problem, but I think a general warning is warranted.)

Comment: Additionally, I feel that getNamespace should be implemented too (trivially)

Comment: I am in control of the `defrecord` so this is exactly what I want. Thanks!